# Java determining the lowest point

Tags: java, point

I have a class called point and a demo class for it.  I am trying to compare the y values from every x,y point I pass into the demo class but I can't seem to wrap my head around retrieving the y values from every point.

```
public class point {

    // instance variables
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // constructor 
    public point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // getter and setter methods 
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;

    }

    public void equals() {
        if (this.x == x && this.y == y) {
            System.out.println("equals");
        }
    }

    public int isLower() {
        if (this.y > y) {
            return y;
        }
        else {
            return this.y;
        }
    }

    public double findLength() {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x - x) * (this.x - x) + (this.y - y) * (this.y - y));

    }
}
```

The demo class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pointDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the x and y coordinates for point1:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int intx = scan.nextInt();
        int inty = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the x and y coordinates for point2:");
        int intx2 = scan.nextInt();
        int inty2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the x and y coordinates for point3:");
        int intx3 = scan.nextInt();
        int inty3 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the x and y coordinates for point4:");
        int intx4 = scan.nextInt();
        int inty5 = scan.nextInt();
        point point1 = new point(intx, inty);
        point point2 = new point(intx2, inty2);
        point point3 = new point(intx3, inty3);
        point point4 = new point(intx4, intx4);

        System.out.println(point1.isLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array or a `java.util.List` to store the points and iterate (`for` or `while`)

Comment: You need to pass another `Point` object as a parameter to `isLower` (and write it accordingly. The idea is to compare *this* point (where the code is running) to the *other* point (that was passed to it).

Comment: Fix your indentation if you're asking people to read your code.

Comment: Class names in Java are title-cased by convention.  The point class should be called Point instead.

Comment: SJuan76 see my answer using Comparator.  I think that is a better approach.  Hand-writing sorting algorithms (unless it's a school assignment) causes code duplication and is prone to error.

Comment: Your question should be stated as a question.  It's more of a presentation of a problem.  Too much is left to the answerer's to infer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want to do is to compare between two points... Then, you'll have to modify `isLower()`

```
   public int isLower(point p){
    if(y > p.y){
     return p.y;
    }
    else{
     return y;
    }
   }

...

System.out.println(point1.isLower(point2));
```

You can enhance this to compare between all of the given points, or store them in an array or a set and return the lowest *y* of all.

Right now your `isLower()` function just compares *point1.y* with *this.y* from *point1* (which equals to *point1.y*) making it *pointless* (sorry about that).

Comment: The Java Class Library has standard interfaces for comparison: Comparator and Comparator.  Your answer above would be improved if it recommended Comparable and its compareTo method.

Comment: Notably and importantly you address the fundamental design flaw and explain a direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this kind of comparison state tracking inside your data object makes it way more complicated than necessary.  In real systems this leads to increased maintenance cost and design fragility.

Making Point implement Comparable or implementing a separator Comparator and using a SortedSet with those or the comparator and taking the last element (assuming your Comparable or Comparator is ascending) is a more idiomatic and Object Oriented option to consider.

```
public class AscendingPointComparator implements Comparator<point> {
   int compare(point a, point b) {
      return a == b ? 0 :
          a == null ? -1 :
          b == null ? 1 :
          a.getX() > b.getX() ? 1 :
          a.getX() < b.getX() ? -1 :
          a.getY() > b.getY() ? 1 :
          a.getY() < b.getY() ? -1 :
          0;
   }
}
```

Addition to your **main** method:

```
SortedSet<point> sortedPoints = new TreeSet<point>(new AscendingPointComparator<point>());
sortedPoints.add(Arrays.asList(point1, point2, point3, point4));
// this is an identity (same reference) comparison
// if you want a value comparison
// implement boolean equals(Object o) in the point class
System.out.println(point1 == sortedPoints.last());
```

Comment: Very high-level answer. I must confess I have been a while trying to cope with all of it.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that my answer is wordy and full of industry context ;). I need to find a tl;dr balance.

Comment: In fairness my answer is a little silly since I construct a List and then add it to a SortedSet.  I probably should have used Collections.sort() instead.  My key goal was to get across reusing library infrastructure and algorithms at a high level rather than hand-coding things.